# Insert bulk Parent and Children rows using SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, query, insert, relational-theory

We receive bulk data from our customers in a spread sheet. I loaded them in a temporary table as of now. I tried to normalize the data and create a parent table and each parent to have 4 or 5 child rows. Is there a way to insert all the parents and their children using queries? I am using MSSQL

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do it using a single query? You can use multiple queries within a SQL transaction to attain atomicity.

Comment: Sorry about that. It need not be a single query.. I just want something where I dont want to write an application to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have normalised you need 2 queries, one to load parents then one to load children (you can only insert into 1 table at a time using sql)

It sounds like you do this ofter, so why not create a file with the sql commands that you use, and each time you do this task open the file up in your databases sql editor window and run (may-be first modifying) these commands. If it always the same sort of task, you could write a script that connects to the database and runs the sql statments you need - then it is a one click or command task.